# Laravel sql query in filterring a prefix

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a model called MyModel, connected to the table my_models and one of it's columns is "unified_code". The unified column stores varchar for example this "500230338383". The unified data is usually of length 12. I will like to fetch all collections from my model with the prefix "5002", how can I achieve that with laravel please?

I know the code below would return empty response. What is the right way

```
$collection = MyModel::where('unified_code', "5002")->get();
```

Comment: `$collection = MyModel::where('unified_code', 'LIKE', "%" . $query .  "%")->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LIKE` with a wildcard.

```
$collection = MyModel::where('unified_code', 'LIKE',  "5002%")->get();
```

Here's the [MySQL documentation about string comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) Note that a wildcard matches anything on that side. So if you want the string to start with `5002`, then only place a wildcard on the right. If you want all strings that contain `5002`, then you would place the wildcard on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$collection = MyModel::where('unified_code', 'like', '5002%')->get();

//with a variable
$collection = MyModel::where('name','like','%'.$variable.'%')->get();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses